# How do you load the default template for an object in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, .net-4.5, resourcedictionary

The title is pretty self-explanatory. I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to load the default template for a particular object from within a DataTemplateSelector.

I know you're gunna ask. Why the heck would you need to do this? WPF will select that template for you if you bind the object to something!

Well, the short answer is: I need to make sure that every DataTemplate that gets returned is a new instance of the template. The control I have this template bound to is reusing it. I am trying to use x:Shared="False" but the control itself doesn't try to obtain the resource again, it's just reusing the one it already has. However, when I use a DataTemplateSelector, the SelectTemplate function get's called each time it requests a fresh UI. So if I can ensure that the DataTemplate being returned here is a new instance, everything should be great.

Except, as long as I am using a default template (ex, no x:Key="" attribute). 
I don't know how to acquire that resource.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, because I never used DataTemplateSelectors so far. But I think you should get the default template by assigning null to the template property of your control. So if you have a
  DataTemplae DefaultTemplate = null;
in your TemplateSelector and return it when needed, it might work

Comment: May I ask, why do you need a new instance of the DataTemplate each time? If you can tell us this, we may be able to offer an alternative solution